# Auth0: Is there a way to switch accounts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am using next-auth to allow users to sign in, but once they are signed in, there is no visible way to switch accounts. Similarly, when they enter wrong credentials, there is no option to sign in with a different account.
Is there a way for users to switch accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Build a wrapper around your app that would store accounts. You want to store a new account in the accounts storage when user add one.

Comment: Thanks Matvii, might have phrased it poorly. I am looking for ways that users can change accounts once they are signed in or sign in with a different account when they enter wrong credentials in auth0.

Comment: To allow multiple accounts. You should store multiple tokens on client side. You need a router that would use account for example id as a top route.

Comment: Storing multiple tokens on the client side seems like a bit of a headache. Is there no simple logout feature/switch accounts feature like with e.g. Google accounts?